# ORA 00918 inner join in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, inner-join

I have this query:

```
select carrier_id, order_id,aircraft_id,quantity 
from orderline 
innerjoin purchaseorder on orderline.order_id = purchaseorder.carrier_id;
```

im getting the ambiguous error, I know I have to use aliases but it doesnt work ie:

```
select carrier_id as cID, order_id as OID,aircraft_id,quantity 
from orderline 
innerjoin purchaseorder on orderline.order_id as OID = purchaseorder.carrier_id as cID
```

it says invalid relational operator ?

thanks for your help guys :)

Comment: it's `inner join` not `innerjoin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a space in your `INNER JOIN`. Not `INNERJOIN`.

```
  select carrier_id, order_id,aircraft_id,quantity 
 from orderline 
 inner join purchaseorder on orderline.order_id = purchaseorder.carrier_id;
```

Also, as the other answerer said, your columns may be ambiguously defined (same column name in each table), so you need to prefix the columns with your table name i.e.( `select orderline.orderid`)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that after you did the `JOIN`, you are selecting some columns. Some of those columns probably have the same name on both tables, and you need to specify wich one is it:

```
select P.carrier_id, O.order_id, O.aircraft_id, P.quantity --use the right prefix
from orderline AS O
inner join purchaseorder AS P
on O.order_id = P.carrier_id;
```

Comment: when I tried it like this, ORA-00933 command not properly ended, with as asterix under AS O